# PHP array to json output

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to create a `json_encode` function which outputs a PHP array like this:

```
{"userA":{"user":"userA","admin":true,"user_id":"000"}}
```

Sadly I just get the following output using my PHP class:

```
{"user":"d4ne","admin":"true","user_id":"000"}
```

My PHP class:

```
<?php
    class add_mod_class {
        function __construct($username, $status){
            $this->username = $username;
            $this->status = $status;
            $this->user_id = '000';
            $this->json_file = 'includes/json/mods.json';
        }

        function get_json(){
            $json_content = file_get_contents($this->json_file);
            $json = json_decode($json_content, true);
            return $json;
        }

        function add_mod(){
            $mods = $this->get_json();
            array_push($mods, $data);

            $ds = array(
                'user' => $this->username,
                'admin' => $this->status,
                'user_id' => $this->user_id
            );

            $new_json_string = json_encode($ds);
            return $new_json_string;
        }

    }
?>
```

Does anyone have a idea why I wouldn't get it working?

**EDIT:**

If i edit the class to push the code into the array like:

```
<?php
    class add_mod_class {
        function __construct($username, $status){
            $this->username = $username;
            $this->status = $status;
            $this->user_id = '000';
            $this->json_file = 'includes/json/mods.json';
        }

        function get_json(){
            $json_content = file_get_contents($this->json_file);
            $json = json_decode($json_content, true);
            return $json;
        }

        function add_mod(){
            $mods = $this->get_json();

            $data[$this->username] = array(
                'user' => $this->username,
                'admin' => $this->status,
                'user_id' => $this->user_id
            );

            array_push($mods, $data);

            $new_json_string = json_encode($mods);
            return $new_json_string;
        }
    }
?>
```

Then the output would look like the following:

```
{"swagg_ma_blue":{"user":"swagg_ma_blue","admin":true,"user_id":"000"},"0":{"d4ne":{"user":"d4ne","admin":"true","user_id":"000"}}}
```

Which contains `"0":`, which shoudlnt be there, anyone a idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code in add_mod() function

```
function add_mod(){
        $mods = $this->get_json();
        array_push($mods, $data);

        $ds[$this->username] = array( //added $this->username
            'user' => $this->username,
            'admin' => $this->status,
            'user_id' => $this->user_id
        );

        $new_json_string = json_encode($ds);
        return $new_json_string;
    }
```

In the above code I added $this->username to have a extra array that you want extra "userA" in the array. and will result as the following.

```
{"userA":{"user":"userA","admin":true,"user_id":"000"}}
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: In a single return this would work perfect, if i fit all the code together it would sadly return this: {"swagg_ma_blue":{"user":"swagg_ma_blue","admin":true,"user_id":"000"},"0":{"d4ne":{"user":"d4ne","admin":"true","user_id":"000"}}} which contains a "0": to much but this is a good thing to start with and this kinda answered the question i asked :)

Answer (score 0):

Is this ok for you:

return json_encode(array($this->username => $ds));

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what do you mean. If you mean array in array you can try this.

```
    $data = array( 'userA'=> array(
          'user' => $this->username,
          'admin' => $this->status,
          'user_id' => $this->user_id
        ));

//{"userA":{"user":"userA","admin":true,"user_id":"000"}}
```

Comment: Yea that works same as the function @Syed Mohamed Aladeen made.Thats why i commented the following: In a single return this would work perfect, if i fit all the code together it would sadly return this: {"swagg_ma_blue":{"user":"swagg_ma_blue","admin":true,"user_id":"000"},"0":{"d4n‌​e":{"user":"d4ne","admin":"true","user_id":"000"}}} which contains a "0": to much but this is a good thing to start with and this kinda answered the question i asked :) and updated my question.